# redirect with variable php using header function

Tags: php, redirect

how do i send a php variable (boolean) with a redirect. For example a flag is set if a condition is true

```
if($url = 'someurl.com'){
   $flag = true;
    header('Location: newpage.php?$flag');
    exit();
}
```

then mypage.php needs to check if its true or false to execute a function

i tried this but it doesn't work

```
header('Location: mypage.php?$flag');
```

perhaps there is a better way of doing it?, this is the 2nd redirect on the page, the first redirect checks checks for a login, then it proceeds to check the $flag variable, no output has been done at this stage

thanks in advance for any advice

Comment: Variables don't get expanded (interpolated) when they're in single-quotes. Use double-quotes instead.

Comment: Isn't `newpage.php?flag=1` something you see every day? That's how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending true in a variable wont work for this, you have to set it to $flag="true"
and you have to use double quotes.

And a single equals means your setting a variable 2 equals means your checking if a variable is equal to something

```
if($url == 'someurl.com'){
   $flag = "true";
    header("Location: newpage.php?$flag");
    exit();
}
```

Comment: thank you, the double quotes done the trick i also had some basic syntax errors that i didn't see after spending to long looking at it, sometime the most basic errors are hardest to find because you think you couldn't make such a mistake,

Answer (score 2):

Variables don't work in single quotes - Also you need to use a comparison operator in an if statement - not an assignment:

```
if($url == 'someurl.com')
{
    $flag = 'someText';
    header("Location: newpage.php?$flag");
    exit();
}
```

or

```
header('Location: mypage.php?'.$flag);
```

Comment: @bartek LMAO, I had it right but then went back to improve the answer. Copied the wrong stuff again. Good show!

Answer (score 0):

try `==` operator to check in `if()` and variable need to correct add with header url use `concat(.)`

```
if($url == 'someurl.com'){
```

and

```
header('Location: newpage.php?'.$flag);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate `php` variable with `string` using dot(`.`) operator.

Try this.

```
header('Location: newpage.php?'.$flag);
```

Also check your condition with comparison operator(`==`)

```
  if($url == 'someurl.com') {
     ....
  }
```

`$url = 'someurl.com'` it means assigning a `string` into `$url`

Answer (score 0):

Change your if condition to

```
 if($url == 'someurl.com'){ ....
```

And the set the header as

```
 header('Location: mypage.php?flag='.$flag);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$flag = '1';
header('Location: newpage.php?flag='.$flag);
```

Then in `newpage.php`, check with `$_GET['flag']`.